# Smartmeter problem in Blackout

Tags: blackout

I read the German original, so the names may be different. Manzano is the protagonist.

Towards the end of the novel, the power suppliers manage to get the people supplied with electricity again. IIRC, Italy was the second country to get its power supply back up (right after France managed to). They only needed to solve the problems with the control software of power plants and were then able to start supplying larger and larger regions with power again.

However, at the beginning of the novel, we're informed that the problem is the smartmeters. Manzano was even able to get power again after manipulating his smartmeter, so the power plants still produced electricity and the grid was stable from time to time.

How is this not a contradiction? Is there any part where they solve the smartmeter problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seem to be multiple attacks occurring simultaneously; 1) The sending of fake shutdown signals to the smart meters (and then flipping them on and off to damage the power grid and power stations) and 2) A Stuxnet-style attack preventing the power stations from shutting down their smart grids and reverting back to their previous 'dumb' state.

As to how the smart meters were fixed, once the unwanted commands were identified, the fix was relatively simply and was implemented via radio.

> “It’s not just the lights they turned out,” said Solarenti. “When they took all those homes and businesses off the power grid, it caused the grids to fall apart. And then, **when we eventually managed to patch together a few relatively stable grids in a couple of regions, another outside command turned the meters back on so that there was a flood of homes and businesses coming back on the grid in an instant. This led to further frequency fluctuations, which overloaded the grid and brought it crashing down again.”**
>
> “So somebody’s playing cat and mouse with us!”
>
> “That’s the bad news. We have good news as well, though. **Now that we know the cause, we can block this command. The IT guys are already working on it—they figure they’ll have it fixed in two hours.**”

As I said above, this didn't resolve the (now underlying) problem of the power grids being broken and the power stations failing and crippled by hacked software.

Comment: For the record, I've only glanced through the novel.

Comment: I can't imagine how this resolves enough of the grid's problems (like the power poles that were blown up or the transformers that caught fire or the ones that were set on fire or the turbines that were damaged) for it to come back on. However, I do now remember that part and it seems like something as minor as the smartmeter problem can indeed have already been fixed way before the end of the novel. The sabotage of the control software might have started a bit later than the manipulation of the smart meters, so it also makes sense that Manzano managed to get the power back up at his place.